# How to set border style for img element in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

This is a beginners question in AngularJS.

I'm writing a simple application to show a few images and allow the user to toggle selection. Only one image should be selected at any one time.

Anyway, how to set the style to change the border for the `img` tag. When the user clicks on an image the style should be set. Neither setting the style or custom style `myStyle` is working (style not applied).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script >
        function myCtrl($scope, $window) {
            $scope.vm = {};
            $scope.vm.Courses = [
              { Id: 1, Name: "Course 1"},
              { Id: 2, Name: "Course 2"}
              ];

            $scope.ToggleCourse = function(imageElement) {
                console.log("id = " + imageElement.id);
                imageElement.style = "{border:'2px solid blue'}"; // doesnt work
                imageElement.myStyle = "{border:'2px solid blue'}"; // neither does this///
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div>
        <div ng-repeat="course in vm.Courses">
            <div>
                <div ng-click="ToggleCourse($event.target)">
                    <label>{{course.Name}}</label>
                    <img id="card{{course.Id}}" src="course.png" ng-style="myStyle">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use ng-class https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. Don't use DOM manipulations at all. Just forget about this possibility until you understand *why*. Instead use [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directives (also don't use ngStyle):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script >
        function myCtrl($scope, $window) {
            $scope.vm = {};
            $scope.vm.Courses = [
              { Id: 1, Name: "Course 1"},
              { Id: 2, Name: "Course 2"}
            ];

            $scope.ToggleCourse = function(course) {
                $scope.selected = course;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        .selected img {border: 2px solid blue;}
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div>
        <div ng-repeat="course in vm.Courses">
            <div>
                <div ng-click="ToggleCourse(course)" ng-class="{selected: course === selected}">
                    <label>{{course.Name}}</label>
                    <img id="card{{course.Id}}" src="course.png" ng-style="myStyle">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems like the right approach: can you elaborate why using class is better than setting style directly?

Comment: Because setting styles directly in controller is not flexible at all. Think about this: tomorrow you will want to change color, add background image, etc. With ngStyle you will have to change controller of your application. However, this change is really CSS related. Why even touch JS code? Separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `ng-style="myStyle"` with:

```
ng-class="myStyle"
```

And define the class in CSS:

```
.myStyle {border: 2px solid #999;}
```

The above is the cleaner method as it just sets the necessary class for the `<img />` element and you can style it, so that the presentation and styles are separated. You can also use the `$scope` and define a function and inject the styles.